# Apply Style Only If Certain Class Comes Before

Tags: css

I am wondering if there is a way to apply a CSS style to an element only if a certain element comes before it. For example, apply my style only if `.foo` appears immediately before `.bar`:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div> //apply style

<div class="dur"></div>
<div class="bar"></div> //do not apply style

<div class="bar"></div> //do not apply style
```

Comment: I would use containers as this behavior tends to happen in groups. Or it'll happen with regard to borders or something like that, and then you could just target `.foo`. I'd like to see your code as sometimes the question asked is asked without realizing other ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with CSS3 you can do

```
.foo + .bar {

}
```

to target a `.bar` which is immediately after a `.foo`.

See [w3.org reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) for variants (for example after but not necessarely immediately after).

Note that [you can't use this on IE7 and it doesn't work perfectly on IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).